# Counting the occurences of value in array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do the following:

From an array `[true, true, false]` I want to find the number of occurrences of the value `true`.

I use the `collect()` to gather the true/false values.
I can check the existence with `is in` but can't count.
Should I unwind?

For every article I want to get the suggestions in the relationship r. Then If it is more than 3 suggestions, I want to set a property in article to be reviewed: true, otherwise false.

```
MATCH (a:author)-[r:reviewedby]-(ar:article)
WITH ar, collect(r.suggest) as suggestions
WITH ar, size(suggestions) as nb_sug, 
RETURN ar, nb_sug
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not making use of false suggestions, for example to calculate a ratio of  true/false , this should work.

```
MATCH (a:author)-[r:reviewedby {suggest:true}]-(ar:article) 
WITH ar, count(r) as true_suggestions 
WHERE true_suggestions >= 3 
RETURN ar
```